# How can I find all datetimes in a list within n minutes of a given value?

Tags: python, list, datetime, min, python-datetime

I have two lists of times (Hour:Min:Sec format) and I've been struggling to compare each entry in `list_a` against all of `list_b` to identify values that fall within 30 minutes:

```
list_a = ["10:26:42", "8:55:43", "7:34:11"]
list_b = ["10:49:20", "8:51:10", "10:34:35", "8:39:47", "7:11:49", "7:42:10"]
```

Expected Output:

```
10:26:42 is within 30m of 10:49:20, 10:34:35
8:55:43 is within 30m of 8:51:10, 8:39:47
7:34:11 is within 30m of 7:11:49, 7:42:10
```

So far what I've been doing is:

```
import datetime

# Convert the Lists to Datetime Format

for data in list_a:
    convert = datetime.datetime.strptime(data,"%H:%M:%S")
    list_a_times.append(convert)

for data in list_b:
    convert = datetime.datetime.strptime(data,"%H:%M:%S")
    list_b_times.append(convert)

# Using a Value of List A, Find the Closest Value in List B

for data in list_a_times:
     closest_to_data = min(list_b_times, key=lambda d: abs(d - data))

     print(data, closest_to_data)
```

This kind of works, but it only finds one nearest value! How can I manipulate the min() function to keep providing values as long as they're within the desired 30 minutes or less?

Comment: Your code doesn't even include a comparison with "30 minutes" anywhere in it.

Comment: Note that you are using `datetime`, which will convert the times to datetime objects, which include a date (1900-1-1, by default). You'll run into a problem with the edge case of a time of 23:50 and another time of 00:10. Purely time-wise, these are within 30 minutes, but when including the date, these will be 23 hours and 40 hours apart.

Comment: @vaizki I know, I believe this is a minor misunderstanding! That's why I ended the post asking how can I manipulate the function to do so, it's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @9769953 Thank you for pointing that out! Should I be using a different approach or should I address that edge case with some kind of if-else tree?

Comment: I don't know; it will depend on the use case and input. The aforementioned times could really be 23:40 hours apart, or 20. Without context, it is not possible to say. You could keep notes of such edge cases (say, all times within 30 minutes of midnight), for future readers (such as yourself) looking at the final results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to compare all combinations, so you need to check all.

Please read the end of the answer for a note on `datetime`/`timedelta`.

Using `itertools.product`:

```
list_a = ['10:26:42', '8:55:43', '7:34:11']
list_b = ['10:49:20', '8:51:10', '10:34:35', '8:39:47', '7:11:49', '7:42:10']

import datetime
from itertools import product

str2time = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")

for a,b in product(map(str2time, list_a), map(str2time, list_b)):
    if abs(a-b).total_seconds() <= 1800:
        print(f'{a:%H:%M:%S} is within 30m of {b:%H:%M:%S}')
```

output:

```
10:26:42 is within 30m of 10:49:20
10:26:42 is within 30m of 10:34:35
08:55:43 is within 30m of 08:51:10
08:55:43 is within 30m of 08:39:47
07:34:11 is within 30m of 07:11:49
07:34:11 is within 30m of 07:42:10
```

Using nested for loops:

```
import datetime

str2time = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")

for a in map(str2time, list_a):
    start = f'{a:%H:%M:%S} is within 30m of'
    for b in map(str2time, list_b):
        if abs(a-b).total_seconds() <= 1800:
            print(f'{start} {b:%H:%M:%S}', end='')
            start = ','
    if start == ',':
        print()
```

output:

```
10:26:42 is within 30m of 10:49:20, 10:34:35
08:55:43 is within 30m of 08:51:10, 08:39:47
07:34:11 is within 30m of 07:11:49, 07:42:10
```

##### note on `datetime`

Using `datetime` without date will default to 1900-01-01, which can have edge effects close to midnight. Instead, you could use `timedelta` objects. With my code you need to change the `str2time` function to:

```
def str2time(s):
    h,m,s = map(int, s.split(':'))
    return datetime.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds
```

And alter a bit the code to be able to convert to string:

```
z = datetime.datetime(1900,1,1)

for a in map(str2time, list_a):
    start = f'{z+a:%H:%M:%S} is within 30m of'
    for b in map(str2time, list_b):
        if abs(a-b).total_seconds() <= 1800:
            print(f'{start} {z+b:%H:%M:%S}', end='')
            start = ','
    if start == ',':
        print()
```

Answer (score 2):

You loop and loot at the absolute time diff of all elements instead of using `min`:

```
list_a = ["10:26:42", "8:55:43", "7:34:11"]
list_b = ["10:49:20", "8:51:10", "10:34:35", "8:39:47", "7:11:49", "7:42:10"]

import datetime
import datetime

# Convert the Lists to Datetime Format
list_a = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d,"%H:%M:%S") for d in list_a]
list_b = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d,"%H:%M:%S") for d in list_b]

for value in list_a:
    for v in list_b:
        if abs(value-v) < datetime.timedelta(minutes=30):
            print (value, "=>", v, "diff: ", (value-v).total_seconds() // 60)
    print()
```

Output:

```
1900-01-01 10:26:42 => 1900-01-01 10:49:20 diff:  -23.0
1900-01-01 10:26:42 => 1900-01-01 10:34:35 diff:  -8.0

1900-01-01 08:55:43 => 1900-01-01 08:51:10 diff:  4.0
1900-01-01 08:55:43 => 1900-01-01 08:39:47 diff:  15.0

1900-01-01 07:34:11 => 1900-01-01 07:11:49 diff:  22.0
1900-01-01 07:34:11 => 1900-01-01 07:42:10 diff:  -8.0
```

This will go wrong for datetimes like 0:05:00 and 23:55:00 because they are lying on different dates though.

You can fix that with a self-written delta calculation:

```
def abs_time_diff(dt1, dt2, *, ignore_date = False):
    if not ignore_date:
        return abs(dt1-dt2)
    # use day before, this day and day after, report minimum
    return min ( (abs(dt1 + datetime.timedelta(days = delta) - dt2) 
                  for delta in range(-1,2)))

list_a = ["0:5:0"]
list_b = ["0:20:0", "23:55:0"]

list_a = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d,"%H:%M:%S")  for d in list_a]
list_b = [datetime.datetime.strptime(d,"%H:%M:%S")  for d in list_b]

for value in list_a:
    for v in list_b:
        print (value, v, abs_time_diff(value,v))
        print (value, v, abs_time_diff(value,v, ignore_date = True))
```

Output:

```
1900-01-01 00:05:00 1900-01-01 00:20:00 0:15:00
1900-01-01 00:05:00 1900-01-01 00:20:00 0:15:00

1900-01-01 00:05:00 1900-01-01 23:55:00 23:50:00 # with date
1900-01-01 00:05:00 1900-01-01 23:55:00 0:10:00  # ignores date
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll go out an suggest using `pandas` for this:

```py
# Convert to pandas datetime series
import pandas as pd
dt_a = pd.Series(list_a, dtype='datetime64[ns]')
dt_b = pd.Series(list_b, dtype='datetime64[ns]')

# Comparison loop
interv_size = '30m'   # Thirty minutes
for el in dt_a:
    hits = df_b.loc[ abs(el - df_b) < interv_size ].dt.time
    print(f'{el.time()} is within {interv_size} of', *hits)
```

The advantage? **You let python deal with the format of your dates**

Answer (score 1):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

list_a = ["10:26:42", "8:55:43", "7:34:11"]
list_b = ["10:49:20", "8:51:10", "10:34:35", "8:39:47", "7:11:49", "7:42:10"]

time_format = "%H:%M:%S"


def convert_to_datetime(time_str):
    return datetime.strptime(time_str, time_format)


# Overriding list_a and list_ to avoid polluting the namespace
# Sorting for simple optimization
list_a = sorted([convert_to_datetime(time_str) for time_str in list_a])
list_b = sorted([convert_to_datetime(time_str) for time_str in list_b])

time_range_limit_in_seconds = timedelta(minutes=30).total_seconds()

result = []
for list_a_datetime in list_a:
    with_in_time_limit = []
    for list_b_datetime in list_b:
        difference_in_seconds = (
            list_a_datetime-list_b_datetime).total_seconds()

        if difference_in_seconds <= time_range_limit_in_seconds:
            # Convert back to string
            with_in_time_limit.append(
                list_b_datetime.strftime(time_format)
            )

        # Since the list is sorted, all the rest don't fall in time range
        if difference_in_seconds < 0:
            break

    print(list_a_datetime.strftime(time_format), with_in_time_limit)
```