# How can I use the python map() function to handle a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, datetime, tuples, absolute-value

I currently have two lists and a working script that when given an element from `list_a`, finds all datetimes from `list_b` that are within 30 minutes. The community helped me with it in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70682951/how-can-i-find-all-datetimes-in-a-list-within-n-minutes-of-a-given-value).

I replaced one of the lists with a list of tuples and have been trying to reconcile that in the script -- I'll explain some of the modifications I tried to make down below.

```
# Old Set of Two Lists
list_a = ["10:26:42", "8:55:43", "7:34:11"]
list_b = ["10:49:20", "8:51:10", "10:34:35", "8:39:47", "7:11:49", "7:42:10"]

# Previous Output
10:26:42 is within 30m of 10:49:20, 10:34:35
08:55:43 is within 30m of 08:51:10, 08:39:47
07:34:11 is within 30m of 07:11:49, 07:42:10
```

```
# Old List and New List of Tuples
my_flights = ["10:26:42", "8:55:43", "7:34:11"]
alt_flights = [("10:49:20", "Frontier"), ("8:51:10", "Southwest"), ("10:34:35", "Jet Blue"), ("8:39:47", "Delta"), ("7:11:49", "Spirit"), ("7:42:10", "American"]

# Desired Output
10:26:42 is within 30m of Frontier, Jet Blue at 10:49:20, 10:34:35
10:26:42 is within 30m of Southwest, Delta at 08:51:10, 08:39:47
10:26:42 is within 30m of Spirit, American at 07:11:49, 07:42:10
```

The working script for the old set of two lists is below, what I'm trying to do is (1) replace `list_a` with `my_flights` (2) replace `list_b` with `alt_flights` and (3) use the names in `alt_flights` with my output!

```
def str2time(s):
    h,m,s = map(int, s.split(':'))
    return datetime.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds

z = datetime.datetime(1900,1,1)

for a in map(str2time, list_a):
    start = f'{z+a:%H:%M:%S} is within 30m of'

    for b in map(str2time, list_b):
        if abs(a-b).total_seconds() <= 1800:
            print(f'{start} {z+b:%H:%M:%S}', end='')
            start = ','

    if start == ',':
        print()
```

Attempted Modifications:
I thought I could change `list_b` into `for b in map(str2time, alt_flights[0][0])` and reference `alt_flights[0][1]` later to pull out the airline name, but that would throw an error with `str2time()`. Then I thought I could make a check underneath `if abs(a-b).total_seconds() <= 1800:` that would check `if b in alt_flights` which would grab the current airline name value of `list_b[0][1]`. But, both of those failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping the times in `alt_flights` before the loop, it might be easier to read if you pass the time data to `str2time` during printing. If you replace

```
for b in map(str2time, list_b):
    if abs(a-b).total_seconds() <= 1800:
        print(f'{start} {z+b:%H:%M:%S}', end='')
```

with

```
for time, airline in alt_flights:
    if abs(a - str2time(time)).total_seconds() <= 1800:
        print(f"{start} {str2time(time)} {airline}", end='')
```

the code will work as expected.

The full second iteration:

```
for a in map(str2time, my_flights):
    start = f'{z+a:%H:%M:%S} is within 30m of'

    for time, airline in alt_flights:
        if abs(a - str2time(time)).total_seconds() <= 1800:
            print(f"{start} {str2time(time)} {airline}", end='')
            start = ','

    if start == ',':
        print()
```

Output:

```
10:26:42 is within 30m of 10:49:20 Frontier, 10:34:35 Jet Blue
08:55:43 is within 30m of 8:51:10 Southwest, 8:39:47 Delta
07:34:11 is within 30m of 7:11:49 Spirit, 7:42:10 American
```

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you **need** to use `map`?

```
for b_time_str, b_name in alt_flights:
    b_time = str2time(b_time_str)
    if abs(a-b_time).total_seconds() <= 1800:
        print(f"{start} {z+b_time:%H:%M:%S} {b_name}")
```

Comment: Instead of ```print(f"{start} {z+b:%H:%M:%S} {b_name}")``` do you mean ```print(f"{start} {z+b_time:%H:%M:%S} {b_name}")```? I get a ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'``` on that line even with the change

Comment: Ah, yes - my bad. I've edited the snippet.